# Failed to parse SIP message when using cyrillic in display name

Tags: android, sip, imsdroid

I am trying to build sip client for android based on imsdroid project, but I found issue when display name of caller in cyrillic, imsdroid can't parse sip message with error, and application doesn't notify about incoming call, just message in log. How to fix it?

```
E/tinyWRAP: ***[DOUBANGO ERROR]: function: "tsip_message_parse()" 
file: "src/parsers/tsip_parser_message.c" 
line: "226" 
MSG: Failed to parse SIP message: Онищук Роман"<sip:************@****.***>;tag=19faa240
Call-ID: yMmeJFsAmbxtCEH1KhLTKg..
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, UPDATE, REGISTER, INFO, REFER, MESSAGE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: replaces
User-Agent: Softswitch2
x-comm-id: 42:812079507
x-comm-context: 2564170904
Content-Length: 263

v=0
o=- 18446744073607522016 18446744073607522016 IN IP4 81.88.86.144
s=-
c=IN IP4 81.88.86.144
t=0 0
m=audio 21702 RTP/AVP 8 101
c=IN IP4 81.88.86.144
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sdpmangled:yes
```

Sip messages:

```
INVITE sip:************@************:37081;transport=tcp SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP ************:5060;branch=z9hG4bKdf9d.9ac271c3.1
Max-Forwards: 69
Contact: <sip:************@************;transport=tcp;did=5c9.2e7a0043>
To: <sip:************@************.************>
From: "Онищук Роман"<sip:************@************>;tag=5b8f7e13
Call-ID: tdtIfNVVpRH-fyyCudszFA..
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: INVITE, ACK, CANCEL, OPTIONS, BYE, UPDATE, REGISTER, INFO, REFER, MESSAGE
Content-Type: application/sdp
Supported: replaces
User-Agent: Softswitch2
x-comm-id: 81:280930576
x-comm-context: 2569789053
Content-Length: 241

v=0
o=- 253558864 253558864 IN IP4 ************
s=-
c=IN IP4 ************
t=0 0
m=audio 12628 RTP/AVP 8 101
c=IN IP4 ************
a=rtpmap:8 PCMA/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=fmtp:101 0-16
a=ptime:20
a=sdpmangled:yes
OPTIONS sip:193.19.229.154:45863;transport=TCP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP ************:5060;branch=z9hG4bK9027956
From: sip:nat_pinger@************;tag=f758ea6
To: sip:193.19.229.154:45863;transport=TCP
Call-ID: 8f329615-2861fb01-467b9@************
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP ************:5060;branch=z9hG4bK9027956
From: <sip:nat_pinger@************>;tag=f758ea6
To: <sip:193.19.229.154:45863>;tag=1890429516;transport=TCP
Contact: <sip:nat_pinger@************:37081;transport=tcp>
Call-ID: 8f329615-2861fb01-467b9@************
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0

OPTIONS sip:193.19.229.154:45863;transport=TCP SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP ************:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1842876
From: sip:nat_pinger@************;tag=7a8c4651
To: sip:193.19.229.154:45863;transport=TCP
Call-ID: 8f329615-aa9557f1-877b9@************
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP ************:5060;branch=z9hG4bK1842876
From: <sip:nat_pinger@************>;tag=7a8c4651
To: <sip:193.19.229.154:45863>;tag=485518869;transport=TCP
Contact: <sip:nat_pinger@************:37081;transport=tcp>
Call-ID: 8f329615-aa9557f1-877b9@************
CSeq: 1 OPTIONS
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a copy/paste issue, or just a log issue. However, the header should have a mandatory **"** char at the beginning.

Comment: @AymericM I added sip messages to my question and header looks good.

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem?